# Strange z-fighting-like happening only in textured view for certain models

Tags: modeling, shaders, z-fighting

I bought a collection of models that all came in a single model file (bad form already, I know). So I started working on splitting the models into each of their own files. This is when I notice that when in textured view, there is some weird z-fighting going on.

To narrow it down, I selected a single face in part of a model, then selected connected with sharp edges as a separator, so I only got part of the model (which is shown in the video). I turned on x-ray to select a face to verify that I'm only selecting a single face, thinking that there may be duplicate meshes on top of each other. Nothing. I did a point merge with a very small radius, but nothing merged. I'm convinced that the mesh itself is not fighting with a copy.

Since it only happens in textured view mode, I cleared the material and created a new BSDF shader with no textures attached to it, which is what you see in the video. So it seems to rule out the shading.

I can't figure out what is causing this. Any ideas?

[image]

Face orientation/normals:
[image: face orientation]

Strange z-fighting-like happening:
[image: z-fighting]

Video showing the issue:
https://youtu.be/PBJmexufsz8

Comment: have you try an Object Data >Geometry Data > Clear Custom Split Normals Data?

Comment: This looks not like z-fighting, it appears to be a face normals artifact caused by some transparency. That's why it only shows on textured view.

Comment: @moonboots Where do I find Object Data? Is that a menu option somewhere?

Comment: in the Properties panel, bottom right panel by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model doesn't use transparency but you have set *Blend Mode* to `Alpha Blend`  in the material's setting together with the option `[X]` *Show Backface*. That's a bad combo and causes the so-called [sorting problem](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/eevee/materials/settings.html#sorting-problem).

Quote from the documentation (*Show Backside* is the *Show Backface* option):

> **Show Backside**
>
> If enabled, all transparent fragments will be rendered. If disabled, only the front-most surface fragments will be rendered.
> *Disable this option to ensure correct appearance of transparency from
> any point of view. When using Alpha Blending this option should be
> disabled because with Alpha Blending, the order in which triangles are
> sorted is important.*

To fix this uncheck the `[ ]` *Show Backface* option.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you! The model was imported from an OBJ file, so I'm surprised Blender set it like that. I suppose there must be something in the OBJ file that Blender looks at and uses for that setting.