# Alpha blend not working on model texture

Tags: transparency

I imported a model from the DS game Phantom Hourglass. The eye textures are not transparent, as you can see below. They show as transparent (i.e. with a checkered background) on the UV editor. I've set them to alpha blend as you can see in the image, and they haven't become transparent. Am I missing a setting or something? I recall doing this with this exact model sometime last year and it worked. (that old file has since been lost)

UPDATE: This was referred to [another question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/276661/107598) that supposedly could fix this issue simply by unchecking "Show Backface." Unfortunately, that changes nothing in my case.

Update: attempting to add .blend file:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. can you share your blend file https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Oh, it didn't solve your problem. So I've voted to reopen your question again. As *Harry McKenzie* suggested It would help if you could share the blend file. If you don't want to share the model for some reason, you can just separate the eyes, add them to a new blend file and share this one.

Comment: hard to determine anything without a blend file so the only thing i could say is try changing the blend mode to alpha clip

Comment: For future reference, you need to pack images (File > External Data > Pack Resources) before you upload a .blend. Otherwise when we open the .blend we won't get any of the textures.

Answer (score 2):

The model was imported from a .dae file. Unfortunately Blender's .dae importer [doesn't handle transparent textures at all](https://developer.blender.org/T98920).

In this case you'll need to manually hook up the texture's Alpha socket to the Principled Alpha (shown below) for all the materials with transparent textures.

[image]

With this (and an appropriate blend mode) the alpha should work.

Comment: Wow. Thanks. That worked instantly, and it was really easy, but I never would have thought to do something like that.